# Get list of Processes that utilize GPU?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to get the list of processes that utilize GPU, to detect if there's any game running.

is there any other method to achieve this?

I found this [discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/98jpqa/net_core_how_to_detect_gpuaccelerated_windows/) but it's not working and I cannot find any documentation on `Win32_PerfFormattedData_GPUPerformanceCounters_GPUEngine`